# ASP.NET site maintenance tip

Tags: asp.net

I am planning to shift my site from one host to other. Any best practices to follow while moving the site?

- my site is always accessed using both `http://mysomesite.com` and `http://www.mysomesite.com`. I have not set redirection from `http` to `http://www`. Should I be doing it now?

When the nameservers are updated, how do I inform the users? Any way in ASP.NET to put the site in maintenance mode?

UPDATE: I meant to ask should I redirect `http://mysomesite.com` to `http://www.somesite.com` or is it OK to leave it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your last question, yes there is, create a file called `App_Offline.htm`, and place it in the root directory. It will end all sessions and show only that page. Rename/delete it to stop it.

Regarding the first part, well that's more sys admin, but yes, you should have non-www and www both go to your site, in general.